# Get all users with role in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, roles

I'm working in this Laravel project which has this structure

**users**: id | first_name |...

**roles**: id | name

**assigned_roles**: id | user_id | role_id

I think this is quite obvious :p

**User model**

```
class User extends ConfideUser {
use HasRole;

public function Roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role','assigned_roles');
}
```

**Role model**

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{
public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','assigned_roles');
}


}
```

I'm looking for a way to get all users with a specified role in this case 'Teacher'. I've tried this:

```
$students = User::with(array('Roles' => function($query) {
        $query->where('name','Teacher');
    }))
    ->get();
    return $students;
```

but this always returns an array of all users.

would anyone know why that's so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you're currently asking laravel for in your `$students` query, is 'give me all the students, and for each student get me all of their roles if the role is teacher'

Try using the `whereHas`

```
$students = User::whereHas(
    'roles', function($q){
        $q->where('name', 'Teacher');
    }
)->get();
```

This should get you the users, but only where they have a role where the name is teacher.

Comment: Are there other ways to retrieve this, because this might have performance issues.  Should we consider using index on user_id on role?

Comment: You could use this package which is very nice, https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [spatie/laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction) or [backpack/permissionmanager](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/permissionmanager) you can simply do:

```
$teachers = User::role('Teacher')->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to get all users with a list of potentials roles:

```
$authorizedRoles = ['Teacher', 'Professor', 'Super professor'];

$users = User::whereHas('roles', static function ($query) use ($authorizedRoles) {
                    return $query->whereIn('name', $authorizedRoles);
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This.

```
Role::where('rolename', 'user')->first()->users()->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Are using laravel-permission package then,

In Controller,

```
$rolesWithUserCount = Role::withCount('users')->get();
```

In Blade File,

```
@foreach ($rolesWithUserCount as $item)
          {{ $item->name }}
          {{$item->users_count }}
@endforeach
```

OutPut:

```
Role1 Role1Count 
Role2 Role2Count
 ....
```

For More:
VISIT: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 0):

This would work exactly as intended:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles' => function($q){$q->where('name', 'Teacher');})->get();
```